# Populating a column based off of values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, data-processing

Hi I am working with `pandas` to manipulate some lab data. I currently have a `data frame` with 5 columns.

- The first three columns(Analyte,CAS NO(1), and Value) are in the correct order.
- The last two columns(CAS NO 2 and Value 2) are not.

Is there a way to align CAS No(2) and Value(2) with the first three columns based off of matching CAS Numbers(aka CAS NO(2)=CAS(NO1).

I am new to `python` and `pandas`. Thank you for your help

[image: CAS NO DATA]

Answer (score 1):

you can reorder the columns by reassigning the df variable as a slice of itself indexed on a list whose entries are the column names in question.

```py
colidx = ['Analyte', 'CAS NO(1)', 'CAS NO(2)']
df = df[colidx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better provide input data in text format so we can copy-paste it. I understand you question like this: You need to sort two last columns together, so that CAS NO(2) matches CAS NO(1).

Since `CAS NO(2)=CAS(NO1)` you then do not need duplicated `CAS NO(2)` column, right?

Split off two last columns and make a Series from it, then convert that series to dict, and use that dict to map new values.

```
# Split 2 last columns and assign index.
df_tmp = df[['CAS NO(2)', 'Value(2)']]
df_tmp = df_tmp.set_index('CAS NO(2)')

# Keep only 3 first columns of original dataframe
df = df[['Analyte',' CASNo(1)', 'Value(1)']]

# Now copy the CasNO(1) to CAS NO(2)
df['CAS NO(2)'] = df['CasNO(1)']

# Now create Value(2) column on original dataframe
df['Value(2)'] = df['CASNo(1)'].map(df_tmp.to_dict()['Value(2)'])
```

Comment: I get the following error when I get to step 3:                                  SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create an example of your table
list_CASNo1 = ['71-43-2', '100-41-4', np.nan, '1634-04-4']
list_Val1 = [np.nan]*len(list_CASNo1)
list_CASNo2 = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '100-41-4']
list_Val2 = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '18']

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(list_CASNo1, list_Val1, list_CASNo2, list_Val2), columns =['CASNo(1)','Value(1)','CAS NO(2)','Value(2)'], index = ['Benzene','Ethylbenzene','Gasonline Range Organics','Methyl-tert-butyl ether'])

#split the data to two dataframes
df1 = df[['CASNo(1)','Value(1)']]
df2 = df[['CAS NO(2)','Value(2)']]

#merge df2 to df1 based on the specified columns
#reset_index and set_index will take care
#that df_adjusted will have the same index names as df1
df_adjusted = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.dropna(),
                                      how = 'left',
                                      left_on = 'CASNo(1)',
                                      right_on = 'CAS NO(2)').set_index('index')
```

but be careful with duplicates in your columns, those will cause the merge to fail..